# Is there a way to minimise risk when HR see I update my linkedin profile

Tags: resume, human-resources, linkedin

One year ago, I joined my current company, but at that time I did not update my LinkedIn profile, now I want to update it.

However, I am worried whether my company HR would monitor my profile from time to time (my company is small size)and I don't know what she'll think about this change?

PS: I am not updating my job seeking status, just want to add my current company to my work record.

Comment: It's normal for users to regularly update their profiles, and unlikely an employer is actively monitoring for it. People have better things to do. Putting your current position is usually seen as a good thing by your employer as it will make their company page look more complete if they have one. -- (fyi, when you update LinkedIn jobs, it gives you an option if you want to notify your contacts or not)

Comment: I have the same question as @JoeStrazzere. If anyone at your company - your manager, HR, or anyone else - has issues with you keeping your public profiles up-to-date with your latest work and accomplishments, that is probably a sign of larger issues. I tend to review and revise my public profiles at least a couple of times a year, even if I'm not actively looking for a job. It makes it easier for people to find me and it's ready if I ever do see the need to apply for a new job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go ahead and update, you don't really need to worry about what HR thinks. Chances are, no one really cares. If at all, they should appreciate the fact that you're keeping your profile up-to date which reflects you work for the organization.

That said, in general, HR simply does not go and monitor online profile / job listing sites to check if an employee is looking for a new job. They have other things to take care of, and even if they wanted to check whether an employee is looking for a job change or not, there are better ways to do that (like: having feedback from managers, 1:1 meetings etc.), and knowing those ways are part of *their* job. You need not worry.

Comment: I think it's worth noting for others in similar scenarios that while HR and management wouldn't _routinely_ monitor LinkedIn, they may check it if OP has openly complained or is visibly brewing upsets. Even then, unless it's a very toxic environment, it's more likely to be about "do we need to start recruiting/prepping a replacement".  In the scenario OP has described, they shouldn't have anything to worry about.

Comment: Although HR may not check linkedin of people, when you add a new position inside of their company in the default linekdin settings that will give them a notification of the change. So they will know that this happened.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul which is nothing unusual, anyways. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh for you and me, sure, and yet I know companies where linkedin update == X is looking for a new job, which is not very far fetched as that's when most people polish their online presence hah.

Answer (score 0):

### It depends on the nature of the HR department

Adding your current company to your work can only be a good thing in any case.

Its when you change your future status that things become questionable - at this point hopefully you can predict how the organisation will take the discovery that you're looking for new work.

HR in smaller organisations is often done in an informal way, so anything could happen. You don't have to worry about this yet.